# Why isn't it possible to cast to a timestamp in an index in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, index, timestamp, cast, postgresql-12

I am working with a JSON document which I receive from an external source. In this document, there is a `timestamp` property which corresponds to the textual format of a `timestamp` PostgreSQL data type. So in other words, it can be casted to a `timestamp` type: `(data->>'timestamp')::timestamp`.

I want to use that `timestamp` property in an index. I tried the following:

```
create table t
(
    data    jsonb
);

create index on t(((data->>'timestamp')::timestamp));
```

I am getting:

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Why is this? I understood that casting to a `timestamptz` is not immutable, because of the localization configuration settings which are not static, but I can't apply that logic to a cast to `timestamp`.

Is there still a way to cast my `timestamp` property in the index here?

I am working with PostgreSQL 12, as released a few days ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casts from `text` to `timestamp without time zone` are handled by calling the type input function `timestamp_in`, which is `STABLE`.

The reason is that `timestamp_in` supports some other formats too:

```
SELECT 'now'::timestamp;

         timestamp          
----------------------------
 2019-10-09 09:53:32.026673
(1 row)
```

If you know that your input is always an ISO timestamp and this cannot happen, define your own conversion function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION text2ts(text) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?$'
            THEN CAST($1 AS timestamp without time zone)
       END$$;
```

You can use that in your queries and indexes.

If you lack paranoia and are sure of your data quality, you can omit the test. That will improve performance, but you risk index corruption if somebody sneaks something like `now` into the data.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I did not think about for support for `now` and such. Now I get it why such cast is not immutable, as the `current timestamp` is of course not a static. I'll make use of such custom function `text2ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
create table t
(
    data    jsonb,
    data_timestamp TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((data->>'timestamp')::timestamp) STORED
);

create index on t(data_timestamp);
```

---

From comments:

> I also tried that (I forgot to mention that in the question), that gives the same error: ERROR: generation expression is not immutable.

If so the only way which I see is to use static column which' value is generated by INSERT and UPDATE triggers. And index by it.

Comment: I also tried that (I forgot to mention that in the question), that gives the same error: `ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable`.

Comment: @basicsuperuser If so the only way which I see is to use static column which' value is generated by INSERT and UPDATE triggers. And index by it.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll apply it. But maybe one step back first, why is the cast not immutable?

Comment: *why is the cast not immutable?* It is dependent by server's timezone settings which are dynamic.

Comment: I understand that's the case for `timestamptz`. But I can't see why that is for `timestamp`. As far as I understand, there are no timezone settings in play here?